# AWS Schema conversion in public schema Pgsql

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, aws-dms, aws-sct

Using AWS conversion tool
I am suppose to MS-SQL conversion into PostgreSQL, Its converting but its creating new schema.

I have a public schema and I need to convert into this schema only, Is there any way to select existing schema, by default its creating schema with name of source database.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code that does the migration

Comment: I am using aws conversion tool software

Comment: I think pgloader does the same...

Comment: A link might be handy?

Comment: by aws-conversion - do you mean aws-dms?.. or "AWS Schema Conversion Tool"?.. the tag is poorly described

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_SchemaConversionTool.Mapping.html You can create mapping rules for database and schema...